# $.getJSON returns undefined then returns requested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got myself stuck in a situation. I was coding a Wikipedia search tool for a personal practice project, but I've ran into a small error. When a user enters a word into the search bar, the input will be store into the data parameter of `$.getJSON`, then the response will return a array of title and description objects based on the word entered in the search bar. The `$.getJSON` function will display 5 sets of a title and it's description in a list format in the designated HTML. Simple enough, but the issue is the `$.getJSON` function will display the wording `"undefined"`, then continue to display the required set of titles and descriptions. Below I have listed my JS coding for your viewing. Also, the full code can be viewed at my [codepen](https://codepen.io/zzmarineszz/pen/VrmeKY).

Can anyone give me a heads up of what might be the issue. As `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, that might be the issue, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Thanks in advance!

```
$("#search-word").on("keydown", function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = {search: $(this).val()};
  getWikiInfo(input);
}
});//search end

function getWikiInfo(input) {
var wikipApi = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&callback=?";
var getWikipHtml = function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  var wikipHtml;
  for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    wikipHtml += '<div class="list"><h3>' + response[1][i] + '</h3><p>' + response[2][i] + '</p></div>';
  }
  $("#list-container").html(wikipHtml);
  }
$.getJSON(wikipApi, input, getWikipHtml);
}//getWikiInfo end
```

Comment: first of all use `var wikipHtml='';` instead of `var wikipHtml;`

Comment: You're fluently adding HTML from a third party source, what if they send you a bomb?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do minor change. Initialize `wikipHtml` to empty string and check if the `response[1][i]` is not `undefined`. Below is the updated code:

```
var wikipHtml = '';
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  if (response[1][i] !== undefined)
    wikipHtml += '<div class="list"><h3>' + response[1][i] + '</h3><p>' + response[2][i] + '</p></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not initializing `wikipHtml` before appending to it, but I would strongly advise that you use proper DOM manipulation instead of building your HTML using string concatenation:

```js
$("#search-word").on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input = {
      search: $(this).val()
    };
    getWikiInfo(input);
  }
}); //search end

function getWikiInfo(input) {
  var wikipApi = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&callback=?";
  var getWikipHtml = function(response) {
    var content = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(i) {
      return $('<div class="list">')
        .append($('<h3>').text(response[1][i]))
        .append($('<p>').text(response[2][i]));
    });

    $("#list-container").html(content);
  }
  $.getJSON(wikipApi, input, getWikipHtml);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='search-word' type='text' />
<div id='list-container'></div>
```